# Cannot read the json object in react

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to make a json webapp which reads from apis and prints the result into a list.

The problem is that i cannot read the complete json object on render.

```
console.log(this.state.coinInfo);
```

coinInfo is a json object looking like:

```
 quantstamp: {id: "quantstamp", name: "Quantstamp", symbol: "QSP", rank: "107", price_usd: "0.446127", …},   
 vechain: {id: "vechain", name: "VeChain", symbol: "VEN", rank: "30", price_usd: "5.80186", …}
```

writing:

```
 this.state.coinInfo["vechain"] works, but
 this.state.coinInfo["vechain"].id says undefined.
```

I would love to get the coinInfo informations into the

element on render.

Here is the full code:

```
var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      coinListJson: "json/coinlist.json",
      coinList: [],
      coinInfo: {}
    }
  },
  createDashboard: function(event) {},
  componentDidMount: function() {
    // Is there a React-y way to avoid rebinding `this`? fat arrow?
    var th = this;
    var coinListBuffer;
    var coinInfoBuffer = {};
    this.serverRequest = axios.get(this.state.coinListJson).then(function(result) {

      coinListBuffer = result.data.coins;
      th.setState({
        coinList: result.data.coins
      })

    }).then(function() {

      //alert("geht "+coinListBuffer[1].id);
      coinListBuffer.map(function(val, index) {
        var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + val.id + "/?convert=EUR";
        th.serverRequest = axios.get(url).then(function(result) {

          coinInfoBuffer[val.id] = result.data;
          console.log(result.data[0]);
          var coinInfoBufferString = coinInfoBuffer;
          th.setState({
            coinInfo: coinInfoBufferString
          })
        })
      })
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    var th = this;
    console.log(this.state.coinInfo);
    return (
      <ul> 
      {
        this.state.coinList.map(function(val, index) {
          return ( 
          <li key={index}> 
            {val.id} 
          </li>);
          })
      } 
      </ul>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: did you try accessing it like `this.state.coinInfo["vechain"]["id"]`? or store `this.state.coinInfo["vechain"]` in a variable and try accessing it with `.id`

Comment: where in your full code example are you trying to access `this.state.coinInfo["vechain"].id`? The only similar thing I see is in your `map` but you're using `coinList` not `coinInfo`. Is that right? 
Also, probably not the issue but worth testing, why are setting `this` to a temp variable of `th` in both the componentDidMount function and your render method? I can imagine that causing state inconsistency at some point. Considering state is a property of `this` in the context of a react component.

Comment: @ewizard `this.state.coinInfo["vechain"]["id"]` and `this.state.coinInfo.vechain.id` are the same thing

Comment: to answer your comment about `this`binding.. just use arrows everywhere. don't use `function`.  https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/

Comment: Also,  if I do a check to make sure `id` is set first it works fine, otherwise it fails with undefined error. Like this as an example `console.log(this.state.coinInfo["vechain"] && this.state.coinInfo["vechain"].id)`